# Understanding and Assigning String values in AS3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, class, timer

I am kinda new to AS3, and I want to figure out how classes and strings work. I have two files:
Main.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {       
            var f1:Flower = new Flower("rose"); 
            var f2:Flower = new Flower("cactus"); 
            var f3:Flower = new Flower("fff");                    
        }
    }
}
```

Flower.as:

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Flower 
    {
        protected var name:String; 
        public function Flower(name:String):void
        {
           setName(name); 

           var updateTimer:Timer;
           updateTimer = new Timer(500.6, 2);
           updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimerFun);
           updateTimer.start();                 
        }

        public function TimerFun(e:TimerEvent):void 
        {
            trace ("test " + getName());
            setName("xxx");
        }       

        public function setName(name:String):void 
        {
            this.name = name; 
        }

        public function getName():String 
        {       
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically from what I understand, every time I create an instance to the class "Flower.as" like this:

```
var f1:Flower = New Flower("rose"));
```

it saves each instance to a new line in the `protected var name` which is located at flower.as. then I can get the names with `getnames`. I placed a timer to check the values, and inside the timer I decided to try to assign a new name with the function `setName("xxx")`, and I set the timer to activate itself twice in order to see how the results change; However,  all it did was replace all of the instances with the value "xxx", it didn't add anything(I expected a new string named "xxx" along with the others). I need an explanation about what

```
var f1 Flower:Flower = New Flower("rose");
```

does exactly and what `setName("xxx")` does. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Okey let me try to explain it for you :)

When u creat this : `var f1:Flower; = new Flower("rose");` u creat a flower and give it name as "rose". But however when u creat a Flower type variable it trigger a `TimerEvent`. When `TimerEvent` start working first line will give to you
"test rose" on your output panel. But the second line is using setName("xxx") function for changing Flower's name.

So when u look your output panel u should see something like this :

test rose

test xxx

I hope this will enough to understand. If u have a question just ask :)

Comment: But there are 3 flowers, and the timer changes all of their names to "xxx" through the function SetName("xxx") instead of just adding a flower.   This is the full output:                                                                               test rose
test Cactus
test fff
test xxx
test xxx
test xxx

Comment: Of course cause 3 flowers using Flower.as once. I mean f1 use Flower.as for itself also f2 and f3 using it for itself.

Comment: And thats why all flower's get name "xxx". Also that timer doing nothing in that class accept changing name's "xxx" :)